# Standard conjectures on positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, motivic-cohomology

In this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83421/voevodskys-counterexample-to-the-existence-of-a-motivic-t-structure?rq=1) of M. Bondarko, he says:

> "the Hodge conjecture implies all the Grothendieck's standard conjectures over base fields of characteristic 0..."

and in [Remarks on Grothendieck's standard conjectures](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.1116v2.pdf) A. Beilinson says:

> "We show that Grothendieck’s standard conjectures (over a field of characteristic zero) follow from either of two other motivic conjectures, namely, that of existence of the motivic t-structure and (a weak version of) Suslin’s Lawson homology conjecture".

**My question is:** What about with standard conjectures in positive characteristic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Over finite fields, the Tate conjecture by itself doesn't imply the standard conjectures, but together with the Hodge conjecture for CM abelian varieties it does (Milne 2002, 2009).

In a little more detail: Milne showed that the Hodge conjecture for CM abelian varieties implies the Tate conjecture for all abelian varieties over the algebraically closure k of a finite field in a 1999 paper (Compositio), and that it implies the Hodge standard conjecture for AVs/k in a 2002 Annals paper. If you assume the Tate conjecture, then the category of motives over k is generated by abelian varieties (mentioned in Milne 1994, Seattle I). In terms of motives, the Hodge standard conjecture says that the pairings defined by ample line bundles are positive for a polarization on the Tannakian category of motives.

Comment: Could you give more precise references?

Comment: What about the Lefschetz type conjecture, and the comparison between numerical and homological equivalence?

Comment: By the Tate conjecture, I mean the equivalent statements of 2.9 of Tate's Seattle article (the order of the pole of the zeta function is equal to the rank of a certain group of algebraic classes). This implies that numerical equivalence equals homological equivalence (ibid.). The Lefschetz standard conjecture says that a certain map of spaces of algebraic cycles is an isomorphism. The Tate conjecture (in the above form) implies that it becomes an isomorphism when tensored with $\mathbb{Q}_l$.